# BeautifulSoup get specific link from class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to make a list with all the links with this html code:

```
<a href="/Comppany_Review-g186338-d1316206-Reviews-name_company1-America.html" class="_60_ydu6b" target="_self">1<!-- -->. <!-- -->namecompany1</a>
```

or

```
<a href="/Comppany_Review-g186338-d1316798-Reviews-name_company2-America.html" class="_60_ydu6b" target="_self">1<!-- -->. <!-- -->namecompany1</a>
```

As you see they share same part of the link and the class. (there are other links on the code with a different class that I don't want to include.

I've tried the following:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text,("lxml"))
    for item in soup.find_all("a",href= True ,):
        comppany_links.append(item.text)
```

but is getting all the words written for the hyperlink and not the real link and not from this specific class. How I can do it?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use CSS-selector to get list of links with specific class name:

```
for item in soup.select("a._60_ydu6b"):
    comppany_links.append(item['href'])
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it gives me the name of the company associated with the hyperlink but what I need is the real hyperlink such as: "/Comppany_Review-g186338-d1316798-Reviews-name_company2-America.html"

Comment: @Piwero try `comppany_links.append(item['href'])`